# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Post request

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I know this question was asked many times but the solutions available online are not working for me.
I  try to make a post request from Angular like this

```
ApiResponse(formVal,url){
 
  return this._Service.AddUser(this.url,formInput)
   .toPromise().then(res=>{
     return res;
   })
}
```

But i get this error **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:61382/api' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** even i  have the corsPolicy in Asp.Net and this happen only for post request.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    c => c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
            services.AddMvc();

}

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
                "default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
                ));
        }
    }
```

Can you help me?Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the headers of your controller and your action ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to move app.UseCors("CorsPolicy") outside if (env.IsDevelopment());

and change your services.AddCors to anotner syntax:

```
services.AddCors(opt =>  opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", c =>
            { 
                c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            }));
```

Comment: Thank you this was the problem